# Bootstrap collapsible button pushing brand element down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the navbar example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Create Single Page</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>


  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

But when the screen enters 261px in width, the collapsible button pushes down the title of the site, making things awkward looking. I tried wrapping the "a tag" with a column but just puts a word break.

Answer (score 0):

261px is extremely narrow -- very few modern devices are so low-resolution, and users generally do not expect a site's content to be usable or readable at this size.

So I'd recommend either ignoring the issue entirely (like Bootstrap itself does) or setting a minimum width in CSS like this (depending on the rest of your markup and styles, you may want to change `body` to a selector for your outermost container):

```
body {
   min-width: 280px;
}
```

Which will add horizontal scrollbars when the page width goes below 280px, instead of attempting to be responsive to so far down a size.

If you absolutely must support a view this narrow, you could add new media queries to the CSS like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 270px) {
   // tiny styles for your site logo here, e.g.:
   .navbar-brand {
      font-size: 0.5em;
   } 
}
```

...to size down the title as needed.